# Can I replace my jQuery validation with HTML5 validation for required field tests?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html

Do I need jQuery validation for **simple input field required / not required checks** if I am using the very latest IE, Firefox and Chrome browsers?

Is there any advantage to my using jQuery if I do not need older browser support with my ASP MVC3 application?

Comment: You can check out caniuse.com for HTML5 features and browser compatibility. There are also several polyfills available that help plug in specific HTML5 features for older browsers

Comment: No matter what you use on the client side, always use server-side validations, too!

Comment: At sometime down the line you WILL need a javascript validation library,so why not start now?  ... HTML5 validation is just not good enough. And heed ComFreek's advice that you should also ALWAYS provide server-side validation too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for jQuery validation if you are using the latest browsers which support the HTML 5 `required` attribute.

Why include an extra script if the browser can handle it for you?

Comment: There is MUCH more to validation than "required"

Comment: i know that but please read the question requirement first "simple input field required / not required checks "

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you both Jquery for old browser and for new browser use HTML5 input feature in order to support all browser of user end as you never know which browser they are using.

I personally use http://www.rapidexp.com/h5form/ it is compatible for all browser it detect wheather the browser support HTML5 or not.If not

**SECOND METHOD**
You can choose manually to detect browser support html5 using `Modernizer` and apply input field as per need just download it and check tutorial for support of input fields

Comment: she already mentioned that she is using the latest versions of browsers

Comment: @rahul she is using it but you are ultimately make site for end users and you don't know that which browser they are using it...

Answer (score 1):

You need jQuery validation or some other JavaScript-driven checks to make all modern browsers do the checks. For example, IE 9 does not implement the `required` attribute. Moreover, browsers that implement it have their own ways of indicating problems to users, and here they use the UI language of the browser, not necessarily with well-formulated texts. To have control over the error messages issued to users, you need JavaScript.